# AWS-ECS vs Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ecs

I am confused to understand the usage of Kubernetes in AWS, when AWS already has a similar service ECS for a while. ECS also does a good job in container orchestration via json/yaml file. What are the advantages of kubernetes over ECS?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately these kinds of tool comparison questions don't really work very well with our ranked Q&A format here and so they generally get closed. Whenever you are comparing two tools, the best course is usually to try both and see which fits your needs and workflow better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both are container orchestration services. ECS is very well integrated with other Amazon Web Services. Kubernetes is cloud-neutral. You can find a good overview [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/what-is-kubernetes/)

Your requirements should tell you which one makes more sense for your needs. Here are some tips to help you understand how each product is positioned. Of course, there's a lot of overlapping and both products are very able to run a production workload.

Go Kubernetes (or [EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/), the AWS Managed Kubernetes service)  if:

- You want cloud portability;
- You want to deploy on-premise;
- You want your developers to use the same tools that run your production workload.

Go [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) (or [Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/), its managed version) if:

- You are comfortable configuring AWS (eg: auto-scaling groups, VPCs, elastic load balancers...);
- You already have a workload running on EC2 and is gradually migrating it to containers;
- You look for a service that is easier to learn;

Comment: Thanks for the answer.